# CSS Flex Navigation Dropdown menu's position is a little bit bad

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make a navigation bar with a dropdown menu. But the dropdown menu from "Product" is a little bit to the right. I want them to start align with their parent "Product". Can someone help me here? Plus, I want to use flex. Without using flex, I'm able to avoid this problem. 
These are the code and you can run to see the result, hover on the "Product".

```css
*{
 list-style: none;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #ff6a00;
}

.nav ul{
 margin:0px;
 display: -webkit-box;/* Chrome */
    display: -moz-box;/* Firefox*/
    display: -ms-flexbox;/* IE 10 */
    display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari 6.1+ */
    display: flex;   
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.nav ul li{
 padding: 0em 1em 0em 1em ;
 line-height: 40px;
 height:40px;
 width:60px;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: all 0.5s;
}

.nav ul a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color:white;
}
.nav ul li:hover{
 background: #313131;
} 

.nav ul li ul{
 padding:0;
 position:absolute;
 width:100px;
 visibility:hidden;
 display:block;
 background: #ff6a00;
}

.nav ul li ul li{
 display:block;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: all 0.5s;
}

.nav ul li:hover ul{
 display:block;
 visibility:visible;
 background: #ff6a00;
}

.nav ul li ul li:hover{
 background: #313131;
}
```

```html
            <nav class="nav">
             <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Product</a>
       <ul>
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">4</a></li>  
       </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
             </ul>
            </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm I'm not sure this is the best way of doing it, however it's a fix nonetheless.

Instead of using an absolute position in `.nav ul li ul`, use a relative one and then set the right property to 1em. To give you the following code:

```
.nav ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  right: 1em;
  width: 100px;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  background: #ff6a00;
}
```

This is to offset the padding in the parent `li` tag: `.nav ul li { padding: 0em 1em 0em 1em; .... }`